# How to get rid of the title bar add to non-gtk applications in elementary OS

Tags: gtk3, elementary-os

In elementary OS Loki, for applications like gvim, urxvt and Xephyr, there will be a title bar added to the application window. Is there anyway to get rid of the title bar?

[Vim with title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h2PR.png)
[urxvt with title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqvK3.png)

Comment: Can you post an image of which title bar to remove?

Answer (score 0):

The title bar is called window decoration. Window decoration depends on the window manager, as stated in the [documentation](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Window.set_decorated.html):

> By default, windows are decorated with a title bar, resize controls,
>   etc.
>
> Some window managers allow GTK+ to disable these decorations, creating
>   a borderless window. If you set the decorated property to false using
>   this function, GTK+ will do its best to convince the window manager
>   not to decorate the window. Depending on the system, this function may
>   not have any effect when called on a window that is already visible,
>   so you should call it before calling show.
>
> On Windows, this function always works, since there’s no window
>   manager policy involved.

Try using `window.set_decorated(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what display manager you are using but I believe Loki ships with GNOME so try looking into some of the Gnome extensions, e.g. [PixelSaver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) or [Maximus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/354/maximus/), though the latter may need a few tweaks as it's been without maintenance for a bit.